# What's proper punctuation for a sentence ending with an abbreviation followed by a parenthetical phrase?

Tags: punctuation, periods, parentheticals

Other questions here address a sentence ending in an abbreviation, and when a sentence-ending abbreviation is followed by a question-mark.  But what about when a sentence-ending abbreviation is followed by a parenthetical phrase?  Do you put a period after the parenthetical?  Example:

> She was previously an engineer at the IBM Corp. (a well-known computer company).

My question is whether that last period is correct.  To me, it looks wrong either way.

I realize that this sentence could easily be rewritten to drop the abbreviation; or to expand it; or to replace the parentheses with, e.g., a comma or dash separator; or to make the parenthetical into a complete & separate sentence.  But those options were not possible in an earlier example I had.

Thanks.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Please don't write an answer in comments.  It short circuits the voting process and makes it difficult to comment on your answer alone.

Comment: @Keeta I view many answer-comments as polite ways of dealing with a question which might, otherwise, receive no answer and be put on hold for 'lacking research'. I would suggest that Roger Sinasohn  is being polite . . .  and now his answer has disappeared.

Comment: @NigelJ Discussion on that should be and has been in meta.  Consensus has been to NOT answer in comments.  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/answering-questions-in-comments